# Import export product error

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to Export product through magento back end

```
System-> Import / Export -> Export --> After that i select Procuct
```

then it shows this error

**Call to a member function getName() on a non-object**

```
 protected function _initCategories()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addNameToResult();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $structure = preg_split('#/+#', $category->getPath());
            $pathSize  = count($structure);
            if ($pathSize > 1) {
                $path = array();
                for ($i = 1; $i < $pathSize; $i++) {
                    $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
                }
                $this->_rootCategories[$category->getId()] = array_shift($path);
                if ($pathSize > 2) {
                    $this->_categories[$category->getId()] = implode('/', $path);
                }
            }

        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a temporary fix

replace line

```
$path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
```

with

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($structure[$i]);
$path[] = $category->getName();
```

And  try to export data again.

The issue is `$structure[$i]` that is `entity_id (category id)` passing in this function. It seems `entity_id` is not a valid in `catalog_category_entity` or category flat tables.

Comment: i changed after that it shows this error Unsupported operand types

Comment: try to debug you are getting id in $structure[$i] this variable

Comment: ok how to getting that $structure[$i]

Comment: $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName(); before this line put code Mage::log("id=>".$structure[$i]); and check your system.log file you are getting the id or not